# Apache - Getting a 403 error on a file that does exist

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, vhosts

I have an Apache server running on Ubuntu 16.04, Now I have the following problem and that is that I get a 403 error on my virtualhost:

`You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

This are the permissions:

[image: Permissions]

This is my .conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.luukwuijster.io

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api.luukwuijster.io/

    <Directory /var/www/html/api.luukwuijster.io/>
        Order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.luukwuijster.io

RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my error.log tells me:

> [Sun Jun 04 14:03:00.957530 2017] [access_compat:error] [pid 24594] [client 77.163.120.254:55376] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/api.luukwuijster.io/

How can I solve this?

### Edit

My ssl conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.luukwuijster.io

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api.luukwuijster.io/

    <Directory /var/www/html/api.luukwuijster.io/>
        Order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.luukwuijster.io
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.luukwuijster.io/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.luukwuijster.io/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: We need to see `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Comment: I've added that.

Comment: Is there perhaps `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/html/api.luukwuijster.io/`?

Comment: No, there are no .htaccess files as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: Removing `Order allow,deny` should help.

Comment: Okay, i did that and it worked, sort of... I have made a directory named "javascript" and in that directory I have made an other directory named "bier" in that folder I have an index.php but when I try to visit that by going to /javascript/bier/index.php I get a 404 error.

Comment: That probably deserves another question.